# Drupal 6 story form submit URL change

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

While submitting Drupal Story form default redirect URL

http://localhost/drupal/?q=node/20

I need to change into

http://localhost/drupal_new/xyz.php?q=node/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new module you can add an implementation of hook_form_alter to check all forms and alter the submit redirect on the appropriate form(s)

```
/*
Implementation of hook_form_alter this method hooks into the submission of story forms 
and redirects appropriately
*/
function my_redirect_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //some code to filter the forms
  if(!$form['#node']->type=='story') {return;}
  //otherwise this is a for we want to fangle
  $form_state['redirect'][0]='http://localhost/drupal_new/xyz.php';
  //this should leave all the ?q=node/xx untouched in $form_State['redirect'][1]
}
```

Code written from memory so YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to implement a custom module for redirection.

Take a look at this page: http://drupal.org/node/134000, specifically the "How to override default form redirection" section. It talks about using the hook_form_alter() function for redirecting.